# Conditional Statement and OR operation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have code in some part of JavaScript like below:

```
$('table#coa-list').find('tbody').append(
    '<tr align="center">'+
    ' <td class="text-nowrap">'+(element.customer_ID == null? '-' : element.customer_name )+'</td>'+
    ' </td>'+
    ' </tr>'               
)
```

The above code represents `if(customer_ID == null){echo ...}`

How can another conditional be added to the expression and combined with an OR operator (i.e. `OR`) in the conditional statement? For example this code `if(customer_ID == null || customer_ID == "0"){echo ...}`

Comment: Do you mean _how can an OR operator be added to the ternary operator/statement (i.e. `(element.customer_ID == null? '-' : element.customer_name )`)?

Comment: @SamOnela yes, that's my question. Any idea to do that?

Comment: Yes - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to perform OR statement? For example this code `if(customer_ID == null || customer_ID == "0"){echo ...}` [in the ternary operator/statement]

One option is to add the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) (i.e. `||`) followed by the other condition:

```
' <td class="text-nowrap">'+((element.customer_ID == null || element.customer_ID == "0")? '-' : element.customer_name )+'</td>'+
```

See a demonstration in the following snippet:

```js
var element = {};

console.log('result of first ternary with OR: ',(element.customer_ID == null || element.customer_ID == "0")? 'null or zero' : element.customer_name );

element.customer_ID = 4;
element.customer_name = 'Bert';

console.log('result of second ternary with OR: ',(element.customer_ID == null || element.customer_ID == "0")? 'null or zero' : element.customer_name );
```

Another possibility is to substitute that expression with a function call. Start by abstracting out the logic into a function:

```
function customerIdIsNullOrZero() {
    return element.customer_ID == null || customer_ID == "0";
}
```

And then to use it, replace the conditional of the ternary operator with a call to that function:

```
' <td class="text-nowrap">'+(customerIdIsNullOrZero()? '-' : element.customer_name )+'</td>'+
```

```js
var element = {};

function customerIdIsNullOrZero() {
    return element.customer_ID == null || element.customer_ID == "0";
}
console.log('result of first ternary with OR: ',customerIdIsNullOrZero()? 'null or zero' : element.customer_name );

element.customer_ID = 4;
element.customer_name = 'Bert';

console.log('result of second ternary with OR: ',customerIdIsNullOrZero()? 'null or zero' : element.customer_name );
```